# Does Unity / Ninject support the latest versions of MVC/WEB API 5.1 and 2.1?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ninject, unity-container, ninject.web.mvc

My application is ASP.NET MVC5.1 and ASP.NET WEB API 2.1. The application 
is small and currently using Microsoft Unity for IOC.

Can someone advise me if they know of any changes needed to make Unity 
work with these very new releases of MVC and Web API?

I am also considering changing to Ninject depending on features.

If I made this move then what features does it offer that the latest version of Unity lacks?  My big concern is that Ninject appears to be well supported whereas Unity seems to be a product that's updated every couple of years when the Microsoft guys have the time to look at it.

Finally how much of a change is needed if I change from Unity to Ninject?

Comment: Have you tested this? What are your findings?

Comment: Steven - I have not yet tested or used either with the new versions of MVC / Web API. Upgrading to these may be one click of a mouse but it's a big problem when things go wrong. This is why I am asking for some advice in advance. Maybe someone out there has been through exactly the same as me. I have not used Ninject and I am also looking for advice about that which could help me and others who use Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use [Unity 3.0.1304.1](http://www.nuget.org/packages/unity) in ASP.NET MVC/WEB API 5.1 and 2.1 project.

I use it, because i can't configure ninject without any bugs for latest mvc core libraries.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about Ninject, but we upgraded our MVC4 to MVC5 application here earlier this week, following the instructions for [How to Upgrade an ASP.NET MVC 4 and Web API Project to ASP.NET MVC 5 and Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2). 
The application is already in production, so I can confirm that Unity supports these new releases! Then you can continue to use it without any damage.

Hope it helps to make your decision.
See ya!